# Invoke a particular view-state in a flow in Spring Web FLow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

In our Spring App, under some test scenarios we need to invoke a particular view-state in a flow which may or may not be the start-state in the flow. Is there any way in which this can be done?

Usually whenever we hit a url, it invokes the start-state of that flow, however here we need to invoke a specific view-state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wanted to do something similar, although much more limited, so that we could provide direct links into the second view-state of the flow as if the user had visited the first view-state and filled its input form with specific data.

You might be able to use this kind of approach to accomplish what you're asking, but then, of course, regular users could do the same thing as well.

So just for reference, here's what we did, making the starting state be an action-state that looks for input parameters and deciding from those where to transition to.

```
<var name="queryForm" class="package.QueryForm"/>

<!-- Allow input parameters for direct links -->
<input name="number"/>
<input name="name"/>

<action-state id="begin">
    <evaluate expression="number != null and name != null"/>
    <transition on="yes" to="findAccount">
        <set name="queryForm.number" value="number"/>
        <set name="queryForm.name" value="name"/>
    </transition>
    <transition on="no" to="formInput"/>
</action-state>

<view-state id="formInput" view="formInput" model="queryForm">
    <transition on="submit" to="findAccount"/>
</view-state>

<action-state id="findAccount">
    <evaluate expression="actionInstance.findAccount"/>
    ....
</action-state>
```